# Making one unique RadioButton across multiple RadioButtonLists?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater control that makes multiple RadioButtonLists. However, I only want one RadioButton (out of all of them) to be selectable at a time. What is the most effective way to do this?

Comment: You can try putting them in the same `ValidationGroup` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.validationgroup.aspx) as suggested here: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/421658/How-to-Validate-multiple-RadioButtonLists-at-once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember reading another thread before and theres a fix for it. I saved the links.

Here was the issue:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q316495

Here is the solution:
http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/EntryId/87/Simple-fix-for-Radio-Button-controls-in-an-ASP-NET-Repeater-using-jQuery

I'm going to look for the thread to see if there is anymore useful information in there.